# How to scale image in button when it's too big

Tags: c#, winforms, button

first, I am sorry if my English is bad. When I work in winform C#, I want to add an image to the button and set it before the text. However, it is too big and I want to scale it smaller to make the button better
[My button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpDZs.png)

[My button I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XLrF.png)

Comment: Hey please shar the code you used to set the buttons image

Comment: If you want an image in that size create an image in that size. Trying to scale down an image here, Winforms does not do anything with vector bases image formats, will just result in a pile of unrecognizable pixels in most cases.

Comment: It doesn't look like a standard button. Please add more details to the question, including the control type, settings, and source code of the control if it's a custom one. Also the sample image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is **how to scale image in button when it's too big** and one way to do this with a standard Winforms `Button` is to use the `Bitmap(Image original, Size newSize)` constructor to scale the image to the size you want (based on the size of the button). Then you can assign it to the `Button.Image` property and set the positions of Image and Text. Here's an example where the original Folder image is 256 x 256:

[image: button with scaled image]

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        initButton();
    }

    private void initButton()
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
            "Images",
            "folder.png");
        int square = buttonWithImage.Height - 4;
        Image resizedImage = 
            new Bitmap(
                Bitmap.FromFile(path),
                new Size(square, square));

        buttonWithImage.Image = resizedImage;
        buttonWithImage.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        buttonWithImage.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
    }
}
```

---

One way of making sure that the image file can be located.

[image: copy if newer]